# Concurrently Pair Matches

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm looking for a java concurrency idiom to pair matches with a large number elements with the highest throughput.

Consider I have "people" coming in from multiple threads. Each "person" is looking for a match. When it finds another waiting "person" it matches with they are both assigned to each other and removed for processing.

I don't want to lock a big structure to change states. Consider Person has getMatch and setMatch. Before being submitted each person's #getMatch is null. But when they unblocked (or are fished) they either have expired because they waited to long for a match or #getMatch is non null.

Some problems with keeping high through put is that if PersonA is submitted at the same time as PersonB. They match each other but PersonB also matches already waiting PersonC. PersonB's state changes to "available" when they are submitted. But PersonA needs to not accidentally get PersonB while PersonB is being matched with PersonC. Make sense? Also, I want to do this in a way that works asynchronously. In other words, I don't want each submitter to have to hold on to a Person on a thread with a waitForMatch type thing.

Again, I dont want requests to have to run on separate threads, but it's okay if there is one additional match maker thread.

Seems like there should be some idioms for this as it appears to be a pretty common thing. But my google searches have come up dry (I may be using the wrong terms).

**UPDATE**

There are a couple of things that make this problem hard for me. One is that I don't want to have objects in memory, I'd like to have all waiting candidates in redis or memcache or something like that. The other is that any person could have several possible matches. Consider an interface like the following:

```
person.getId();         // lets call this an Integer
person.getFriendIds();  // a collection of other person ids
```

Then I have a server that looks something like this:

```
MatchServer:
   submit( personId, expiration ) -> void // non-blocking returns immediately
   isDone( personId ) -> boolean          // either expired or found a match
   getMatch( personId ) -> matchId        // also non-blocking
```

This is for a rest interface and it would use redirects until you got to the result. My first thought was to just have a Cache in MatchServer that was backed by something like redis and has a concurrent weak value hash map for objects that were currently locked and being acted on. Each personId would be wrapped by a persistent state object with states like submitted, matched, and expired.

Following so far? Pretty simple, the submit code did the initial work, it was something like this:

```
public void submit( Person p, long expiration ) {
    MatchStatus incoming = new MatchStatus( p.getId(), expiration );
    if ( !tryMatch( incoming, p.getFriendIds() ) )
        cache.put( p.getId(), incoming ); 
}

public boolean isDone( Integer personId ) {
    MatchStatus status = cache.get( personId );
    status.lock();
    try {
        return status.isMatched() || status.isExpired();

    } finally {
        status.unlock();
    }
}

public boolean tryMatch( MatchStatus incoming, Iterable<Integer> friends ) {
    for ( Integer friend : friends ) {
        if ( match( incoming, friend ) )
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private boolean match( MatchStatus incoming, Integer waitingId ) {
    CallStatus waiting = cache.get( waitingId );
    if ( waiting == null )
        return false;

    waiting.lock();
    try {
        if ( waiting.isMatched() )
            return false;

        waiting.setMatch( incoming.getId() );
        incoming.setMatch( waiting.getId() );

        return true
    } finally {
        waiting.unlock();
    }
}
```

So the problem here is that if two people come in at the same time and they are their only matches they wont find each other. A race condition right? The only way I could see to solve it was to synchronize "tryMatch()". But that kills my throughput. I can't have tryMatch indefinitely loop because I need these to be very short calls.

So what is a better way to approach this? Every solution I come up with forces people in one at a time which isn't great for throughput. For example, creating a background thread and using a blocking queue for putting and taking incoming one at a time.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried?  How about some code samples?  What research have you done.  SO is not your research assistant.

Comment: Can you suggest a better site to get help working out developing ideas? I figured this would be a straight forward question with someone who has the requisite background -- concurrently create matches based on some generic matching criteria in such a way that takes the matches out of play. But I'm happy to ask it somewhere else that is better for less concrete questions.

Comment: This is a pretty intricate problem with a lot of pitfalls.   It's very hard to generalize.  I'd take a whack at it and then circle back with specific problems.

Comment: What happenned to the bounty?  Did you put your own answer up before the bounty expired?

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use a `ConcurrentHashMap`.  I'm assuming that your objects have keys they can match on, e.g. PersonA and PersonB would have a "Person" key.

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Match> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

void addMatch(Match match) {
    boolean success = false;
    while(!success) {
        Match oldMatch = map.remove(match.key);
        if(oldMatch != null) {
            match.setMatch(oldMatch);
            success = true;
       } else if(map.putIfAbsent(match.key, match) == null) {
            success = true;
       }
   }
}
```

You'll keep looping until you either add the match to the map, or until you've removed an existing match and paired it.  `remove` and `putIfAbsent` are both atomic.

**Edit:** Because you want to offload the data to a disk, you can use e.g. [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) to this end, with its [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db.collection.findAndModify) method.  If an object with the key already exists, then the command would remove and return it so that you can pair the old object with the new object and presumably store the pair associated with a new key; if an object with the key doesn't exist then the command stores the object with the key.  This is equivalent to the behavior of `ConcurrentHashMap` except that the data is stored on disk instead of in memory; you don't need to worry about two objects writing at the same time, because the `findAndModify` logic prevents them from inadvertently occupying the same key.

Use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) if you need to serialize your objects to JSON.

There are alternatives to Mongo, e.g. [DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/), although Dynamo is only free for small amounts of data.

**Edit:** Given that the friends lists are not reflexive, I think you can solve this with a combination of MongoDB (or another key-value database with atomic updates) and a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

1. Persons in MongoDB are either "matched" or "unmatched."  (If I say "remove a person from MongoDB", I mean "set the person's state to 'matched.'")
2. When you add a new person, first create a `ConcurrentHashMap<key, boolean>` for it, probably in a global `ConcurrentHashMap<key, ConcurrentHashMap<key, boolean>>`.
3. Iterate through the new person's friends:
4. If a friend is in MongoDB, then use `findAndModify` to atomically set it to "matched," then write the new person to MongoDB with a state of "matched," and finally add the pair to a "Pairs" collection in MongoDB that can be queried by the end user.  Remove the person's `ConcurrentHashMap` from the global map.
5. If the friend isn't in MongoDB, then check to see if that friend has written to the current friend's associated `ConcurrentHashMap`. it has, then do nothing; if it has not, then check to see if the friend has a `ConcurrentHashMap` associated with it; if it does, then set the value associated with the current person's key to "true."  (Note that it's still possible for two friends to have written to each others' hash maps since the current person can't check its own map and modify the friend's map with one atomic operation, but the self hash map check reduces this possibility.)
6. If the person hasn't been matched, then write it to MongoDB in the "unmatched" state, remove its `ConcurrentHashMap` from the global map, and create a delayed task that will iterate through the ids of all of the friends that wrote to the person's `ConcurrentHashMap` (i.e. using `ConcurrentHashMap#keySet()`).  The delay on this task should be random (e.g. `Thread.sleep(500 * rand.nextInt(30))`) so that two friends won't always attempt to match at the same time.  If the current person doesn't have any friends that it needs to re-check, then don't create a delayed task for it.
7. When the delay is up, create a new ConcurrentHashMap for the person, remove the unmatched person from MongoDB, and loop back to Step 1.  If the person is already matched, then don't remove it from MongoDB and terminate the delayed task.

In the common case, a person either matches with a friend, or else fails to match without a friend having been added to the system while iterating through the list of friends (i.e. the person's `ConcurrentHashMap` will be empty).  In case simultaneous writes of friends:

Friend1 and Friend2 are added at the same time.

1. Friend1 writes to Friend2's `ConcurrentHashMap` to indicate that they missed each other.
2. Friend2 writes to Friend1's `ConcurrentHashMap` to indicate the same (this would only occur if Friend2 were to check to see that Friend1 wrote to its map at the same time that Friend1 was writing to it - ordinarily Friend2 would detect that Friend1 had written to its map and so it would not write to Friend1's map).
3. Friend1 and Friend2 both write to MongoDB.  Friend1 randomly gets a 5 second delay on its followup task, Friend2 randomly gets a 15 second delay.
4. Friend1's task fires first, and matches with Friend2.
5. Friend2's task fires second; Friend2 is no longer in MongoDB, so the task immediately terminates.

A few hiccups:

1. It's possible that Friend1 and Friend2 don't both have `ConcurrentHashMaps` associated with them, e.g. if Friend2 is still initializing its hash map at the time that Friend1 checks to see if the map is in memory.  This is fine, because Friend2 will write to Friend1's hash map and so we're guaranteed that the match will eventually be attempted - at least one of them will have a hash map while the other is iterating, since hash map creation precedes iteration.
2. The second iteration of a match may fail if both friends' tasks somehow fired at the same time.  In this case, a person should remove friends from its list if they are in MongoDB in the matched state; they should then take the union of the resulting list with the list of friends who wrote to its `ConcurrentHashMap`, and then the next iteration should use this as the new friend list.  Eventually the person will be matched, or else the person's "re-check" friends list will be emptied.
3. You should increase the task delay on each subsequent iteration in order to increase the probability that two friends' tasks won't run simultaneously (e.g. `Thread.sleep(500 * rand.nextInt(30))` on the first iteration, `Thread.sleep(500 * rand.nextInt(60))` on the second iteration, `Thread.sleep(500 * rand.nextInt(90))` on the third, etc).
4. On subsequent iterations, you must create a person's new `ConcurrentHashMap` before removing the person from MongoDB, otherwise you'll have a data race.  Likewise, you must remove a person from MongoDB while you're iterating through its potential matches, otherwise you might inadvertently match it twice.

**Edit:** Some code:

The method **`addUnmatchedToMongo(person1)`** writes an "unmatched" person1 to MongoDB

**`setToMatched(friend1)`** uses `findAndModify` to atomically set `friend1` to "matched"; the method will return false if `friend1` is already matched or doesn't exist, or will return true if the update was successful

**`isMatched(friend1)`** returns true if `friend1` exists and is matched, and returns false if it doesn't exist or exists and is "unmatched"

```
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, Person>> globalMap;
private DelayQueue<DelayedRetry> delayQueue;
private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

executor.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            Runnable runnable = delayQueue.take();
            executor.execute(runnable);
        }
    }
}

public static void findMatch(Person person, Collection<Person> friends) {
    findMatch(person, friends, 1);
}

public static void findMatch(Person person, Collection<Person> friends, int delayMultiplier) {
    globalMap.put(person.id, new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Person>());
    for(Person friend : friends) {
        if(**setToMatched(friend)**) {
            // write person to MongoDB in "matched" state
            // write "Pair(person, friend)" to MongoDB so it can be queried by the end user
            globalMap.remove(person.id);
            return;
        } else {
            if(**!isMatched(friend)** && globalMap.get(person.id).get(friend.id) == null) {
                // the existence of "friendMap" indicates another thread is currently  trying to match the friend
                ConcurrentHashMap<String, Person> friendMap = globalMap.get(friend.id);
                if(friendMap != null) {
                    friendMap.put(person.id, person);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    **addUnmatchedToMongo(person)**;
    Collection<Person> retryFriends = globalMap.remove(person.id).values();
    if(retryFriends.size() > 0) {
        delayQueue.add(new DelayedRetry(500 * new Random().nextInt(30 * delayMultiplier), person, retryFriends, delayMultiplier));
    }
}

public class DelayedRetry implements Runnable, Delayed {
    private final long delay;
    private final Person person;
    private final Collection<Person> friends;
    private final int delayMultiplier;

    public DelayedRetry(long delay, Person person, Collection<Person> friends, delayMultiplier) {
        this.delay = delay;
        this.person = person;
        this.friends = friends;
        this.delayMultiplier = delayMultiplier;
    }

    public long getDelay(TimeUnit unit) {
        return unit.convert(delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public void run {
        findMatch(person, friends, delayMultiplier + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Something like this would be good but I will have clients periodically looking to see if they have been matched so I will have to have another store that keeps all of these which could take up a lot of memory. Maybe I could use memcache or redis for this. I also have to expire people if they have been waiting for a match for too long. The client calls will most likely come in over REST.

Comment: @Gray I don't see where the race condition is at. Case 1: `remove` succeeds, so a match is found; there isn't a race condition since `remove` is atomic and nothing is added to the map. Case2: `remove` fails, so the map isn't modified and there is no race condition. Case2a: `putIfAbsent` succeeds, this is atomic so again there's no race condition. Case2b: `putIfAbsent` fails, so the map isn't changed and there is no race condition (and we don't exit the loop).

Comment: Sorry @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot.  I missed the while.  Looks good.

Comment: @Gray I added more detail. Hopefully you guys can provide more guidance. Thanks.

Comment: @Gray I also added a bounty since I know it is asking a lot of people.

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot, unfortunately it is not that simple. It is not an atomic findAndModify. Check out the update. I need to go through all the possible friends of a person. Like I said in the post, I don't know how to avoid a race condition without pushing each new submit into a BlockingQueue so that they are handled one by one.

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot and the other thing is that I cannot "remove" it from storage since it needs to be there for a client to poll its results. Are you suggesting two different stores? One for when I submit and another for #isDone?

Comment: @user1888440 if I understand correctly, then each group of friends is reflexive, correct?  Meaning, Person A has five friends, and each of those five friends is friends with Person A and the other four friends.  If this is the case, then you can create a key for each group of friends by concatenating their ids together, e.g. id1|id2|id3|id4.  You would then use `findAndModify` on the document associated with this key, either removing the present occupant or adding the active user.  This way the `findAndModify` logic prevents a race condition.

Comment: @user1888440 and yes, you would use two different collections: one for unmatched persons, and one for matched persons.

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot think of each personA and personB would not have the same list of friends but they would be able to connect if their were each in each other's friends list. I could of course flatten them out as pairs. But that could be a ton of data. But yeah, think of them like google+ social circles.

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot can you add some pseudo-code for this solution? I'm not sure I understand it in its entirety. You can elide all but the important parts and do it as loosely as you can so it's not a huge PITA to put the code in here. I'm not quite visualizing it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I still am not clear on the details of your matching system but I can give you some general guidance.

Fundamentally, you cannot synchronize processes without an atomic read-modify-write capability.  I will not address how you get that from your database because it varies from easy (SQL database with Transaction Isolation) to impossible (some NoSQL databases). If you can't get it from the database then you have no choice but to do the synchronization in memory.

Second, you need to be able to atomically remove two people who are matched from the availability pool at the same time.  But as part of the same atomic operation you need to also verify that both are still available before assigning them to each other.

Third, to maximize throughput, you design the system to *detect* race conditions rather than *prevent* them, and implement a recovery procedure when a race is detected.

All of the above is much easier (and higher performance) to do in memory than in a database.  So I would do it in memory if at all possible.

1. Create an in-memory matching pool ordered by insertion, so every request knows which request came before and which came after. (It's not necessary that this reflect the order of requests made, it just needs to be the order in which they were inserted into the pool.)
2. Request comes in.  Request goes into the in-memory matching pool and database status is changed to 'searching'.
3. The request thread searches the in memory pool for older matching requests.

   1. If one is found, it's a match.
   2. If none is found, the request thread exits.
   3. If, while searching, it is matched by a newer request, it stops searching and lets the newer request remove it from the pool.
4. On match, the newer request notifies the older request to stop searching and both requests are removed from the pool.  If a race is detected, whoever detects it stops/undoes what they are doing and proceeds according to the new information. You have to design the order of race detection to ensure that this does behavior does not result in orphaned matches (sort of the equivalent of deadlocks), but this is completely doable.
5. After the matches are removed from the pool, their database status is updated.
6. A separate worker thread scans the queue in order of oldest to newest and removes expired requests, updating the database with the new status.

In this system the only blocking synchronous actions are being inserted into the match pool and being removed from the match pool and these are separate locks.  (The request thread, before it removes its request from the match pool, has to obtain a lock, see if it is still in the match pool, and if it is not then branch to race recovery procedures.) I believe that is the theoretical limit of how little you can synchronize. (Okay, I guess you also have to block on inserts into the pool when the pool is full, but what else can you do?  If you could create a new pool then you could expand the existing one.)

Note that by ordering the request queue and searching in order you guarantee that the requesting thread can do a complete search.  If it cannot find a search, then the only hope is that a later request will match and that match will be found by the later requesting thread.

Answer (score 0):

Until something better and simpler can be proposed I've gone with super-simple approach. A single background thread processing a BlockingQueue. It doesn't have great throughput but submitters don't have to block. It also has the benefit of not requiring synchronization on the persistent cache of waiters. I can pretty easily change the BlockingQueue to a persistence backed BlockingQueue. Submitters will only have to wait if the queue gets full.

The only issue will be if there are SO many submitters and pollers at once that the processing queue falls hopelessly behind submitters. Here's a simplified implementation of the pump. The match method just iterators though the #getFriendIds and does a keyed lookup to see if the person at that id exists in the redis (or whatever) cache. If they are in the cache then they are matchable. I exchange each other's ids to match them.

```
class HoldPump extends Thread {

    private final BlockingQueue<Incoming> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>( CAPACITY );

    HoldPump() {
        super( "MatchingPump" );
    }

    public void submit( Person p ) {
        Incoming incoming = new Incoming( p.getId(), p.getFriendIds() ) );
        queueProcessing( incoming );
    }

    public void queueProcessing( Incoming incoming ) ... {
        queue.put( incoming );
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while ( true ) {
                Incoming incoming = queue.take();
                tryMatch( incoming );
            }
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            Thread.interrupted();
        }
    }
}



protected void trytMatch( Incoming incoming ) {
    MatchStatus status = incoming.status;

    status.answer( incoming.holdDuration );

    for ( Integer candidate : incoming.candidates ) {
        MatchStatus waiting = waitingForMatchByPersonId.get( candidate );
        if ( waiting != null ) {
            waiting.setMatch( incoming.status.getPersonId() );
            status.setMatch( waiting.getPersonId() )
        }
    }
}
```

The #setMatch method essentially signals a done condition that is part of a reentrant lock in MatchStatus.

Comment: This does not answer the question you asked.  It is not concurrent, it is single threaded, and simply avoids addressing any of the problems you asked about by effectively creating a global processing lock.  It thus has just about the lowest possible throughput you could have without creating a deadlock.  If that's what you did in your program, fine, but please do not mark it as an accepted answer to your question. Future readers of your question will be directed to the accepted answer first and it does them a disservice if the accepted answer doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Well, the solution is concurrent even if the actual match is atomic. Multiple clients can submit themselves and see if they have a match concurrently. And, as far as I can tell, it will have better performance characteristics than the two other answers submitted so far.

Comment: There is a difference between a solution that is sufficient for your program and a solution to the question you asked. With this (or any) solution multiple clients can submit and wait concurrently, but the question was how to concurrently match them, and you are not concurrently matching them, you are serially matching them one at a time. You said in your question "The only way I could see to solve it was to synchronize tryMatch(). But that kills my throughput." This answer synchronizes tryMatch(). It will not produce incorrect results, but it is not a solution to the question you asked.

Comment: Honestly, your steps 1-6 seem vague and underdeveloped. I'm sure it is all very clear in your head but without some code examples (something concrete) I don't see how it would work properly and efficiently. If there is a workable solution that avoids using a pump I will gladly remove the solution from my answer and give the poster a bounty.

Comment: Thank you for un-accepting your answer.  I'm not pushing you to accept mine.  I did not answer with code because you left out some key information in your question: what information is stored in what kind of database with what structure and what transaction isolation capability, how is a match defined, what is the expected size of the eligible (waiting) pool, how computationally hard is it to find a match and can your database effectively do those searches in parallel?  If you have a solution you're happy with you don't need to answer those questions.

Comment: I'm assuming that `tryMatch` iterates through the entire queue; if you replace the queue with a `ConcurrentHashMap` then your `tryMatch` will run in time proportional to the number of friends rather than in time proportional to the size of the queue.  The downside is that it will be more difficult to persist the map than to persist the queue.

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot, I posted code showing the basic idea of #tryMatch. I don't need the signaling on the ReentrantLock condition but it's there in case I ever have a caller that wants to #await a match instead of polling. The queue is just to order and block incoming requests. What I am processing is actually just the concurrent hashmap of already-processed requests. So just proportional to the number of friends. Seeing the above do you have a preference between your implementation and this one? BTW, do you have an email addy? I'd like to contact you.

Comment: @user1888440 if the queue's length is proportional to the number of friends then I don't think there's any advantage to using a map instead of a queue.  You can contact me at loinburger2000 at yahoo.com if you want to discuss this offline.

Answer (score 0):

> ***I want to do this in a way that works asynchronously***

Asynchronous processing = pair of logical queues between "person submitter" and "person matcher":

- One queue for match request
- Another queue for match response
- The core person matcher algorithm works identically whether synchronous or asynchronous
- In other words, asynchronous behaviour is added as a facade/decorator over the top and does not affect the match design.

> ***There are a couple of things that make this problem hard for me. One is that I don't want to have objects in memory, I'd like to have all waiting candidates in redis or memcache or something like that.***

- Probably helpful to describe your requirements/constraints first before jumping to solution.  Sort of language I'd use instead: 
  "I only have 200MB memory available for match processing and wish to maximise performance.  There could be a maximum of 10000 matches pending at any point in time and matches timeout after 30 minutes."
- You don't want storage "in memory" but rather "in cache".  But aren't the two caches you mention 100% "in memory"?  Not obvious to me what they add.  Any specific requirements you think the cache will solve?  Perhaps, as an example, you could store a huge amount of data in 200MB in memory and have a clean, streamlined algorithm with high-performance.

> ***My first thought was to just have a Cache in MatchServer that was backed by something like redis and has a concurrent weak value hash map for objects that were currently locked and being acted on.***

- I suggest you use a concurrent queue and a vanilla hash map: requesters insert into the queue and the matcher thread pulls from the queue and inserts into the vanilla hash map.
- A concurrent hash map is only useful if you have multiple threads operating on it at the same time.  If there's just a single thread operating on it, then a vanilla hash map is fine and superior in performance.  While you could have requesters inserting directly into concurrent hash map, I think this would give too much concurrency contention/locking.
- Here you're talking about locking before you do the match, but this is not necessarily needed.

**1. Solution 1: Serialised Match Processing within a Single Thread**

- All matching done within one "match thread"
- No need for ***any*** locking or transactions - there is no multi-thread contention
- Concurrent queue serializes all incoming requests
- Match thread processes one request at a time, inserting the new person into the hash map
- Run the match for the new person - if a match is found, link the two persons, remove each from hashmap, and return result to the *two* requesters via response queues

**2. Solution 2: Multiple Threads for Match Processing, with *pessimistic locking* with a minimal critical region:**

- Get a reference to the next person (from queue).
- Run the match algorithm for that person without locking (i.e. optimistic match processing)
- Determine the best *candidate* match (if any)
- Then do pessimistic record writes and store:

  - *Then* lock the pair
  - Confirm that they are still both unmatched after they are in the locked state
  - Link them as a match, update to persistent store if needed
  - Unlock

**3. Solution 3: Multiple Threads for Match Processing Using a Transactional Persistent Store and **optimistic locking***:*

- Modify the person class, adding a match timestamp or version number.  This will act as the optimistic locking control flag.
- Get a reference to the next person (from queue, with optional additional "read" from persistent store).
- Run the match algorithm for that person without locking (i.e. optimistic match processing)
- Determine the best *candidate* match (if any)
- Then do optimistic record writes and store:

  - Start a transaction (probably a JTA/DB transaction),
  - Link the two person objects as a match
  - Update the match timestamp / version number on the two person objects (JPA does this automatically via @Version annotation)
  - Update the persistent store (e.g. DB) where the timestamp / version number matches the *old* value  (JPA does this automatically via @Version annotation)
  - Commit the transaction